# Linking Crashlytics with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

We are using crashlytics for almost 2 years and we have lot of crash related info. We are not using Answers.

Now If we move to Firebase-Crashlytics, will my old historical data get migrated? or viewable from firebase console?

Saw few links related to this from fabric/firebase dev but there are no recent updates there. 
https://medium.com/@bonnell/fabric-and-firebaser-here-16ffb98b5afe

Now I see a option to link Fabric Answers with Firebase-Events. And in the steps they mentioned it that this will send the events to Firebase, big-query. Does it mean that old crashes also viewable there?

https://docs.fabric.io/android/answers/android-export-firebase.html

```
2.9.0: February 2, 2018

App teams who use both Fabric and Firebase can now link their apps and use Crashlytics within the Firebase console.
```

This is mentioned in Crashlytics 2.9.0 release notes.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Firebase here. Currently, your historical data will not be migrated. Updates will be posted once that changes, but there haven't been changes which is why there haven't been additional updates :)

Comment: Thanks @Mikebonnell

Comment: Hey Mike, is there are way to actually export data from Firebase Crashlytics into another application that I am developing?